# AccessDeniedException when creating API Gateway through Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to create API Gateway / Lambda stack through Terraform.
This is my `apigateway.tf` file (I added `"aws_api_gateway_authorizer"` as per https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_authorizer):

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "handler_gateway" {
  name        = "captainai_webhook_handler"
  description = "Entry point for captainai webhook handler"

  tags = var.service_tags
}


resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "lambda" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.handler_gateway.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_method.events_post.resource_id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.events_post.http_method

  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                     = aws_lambda_function.handler_lambda.invoke_arn
}


resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "lambda_root" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.handler_gateway.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_method.events_post.resource_id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.events_post.http_method

  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                     = aws_lambda_function.handler_lambda.invoke_arn
}


resource "aws_api_gateway_domain_name" "handler_domain_name" {
  regional_certificate_arn = var.domain_certificate_arn
  domain_name     = var.domain_name
  tags = var.service_tags

  endpoint_configuration {
    types = ["REGIONAL"]
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "events_proxy" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.handler_gateway.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.handler_gateway.root_resource_id
  path_part   = "{proxy+}"
}


resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "events_post" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.handler_gateway.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.events_proxy.id
  http_method   = "POST"
  authorization = "NONE"
}


resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "handler" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda,
    aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda_root,
  ]

  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.handler_gateway.id
  stage_name  = "default"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "invocation_role" {
  name = "api_gateway_auth_invocation"
  path = "/"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "invocation_policy" {
  name = "default"
  role = aws_iam_role.invocation_role.id

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "${aws_lambda_function.handler_lambda.arn}"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}


resource "aws_api_gateway_authorizer" "demo" {
  name                   = "demo"
  rest_api_id            = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.handler_gateway.id
  authorizer_uri         = aws_lambda_function.handler_lambda.invoke_arn
  authorizer_credentials = aws_iam_role.invocation_role.arn
}
```

Unfortunately, it is throwing me the following error, for both `aws_api_gateway_rest_api` and `aws_api_gateway_domain_name`:

```
Error: Error creating API Gateway: AccessDeniedException: 
    status code: 403, request id: ad1c834d-5ba9-462a-ac65-ed9852811632
  on apigateway.tf line 1, in resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "handler_gateway":
   1: resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "handler_gateway" {
Error: Error creating API Gateway Domain Name: AccessDeniedException: 
    status code: 403, request id: 1c11fda2-5618-4ae0-aeac-783288535d57
  on apigateway.tf line 31, in resource "aws_api_gateway_domain_name" "handler_domain_name":
  31: resource "aws_api_gateway_domain_name" "handler_domain_name" {
```

The only other thing that comes to my mind that I should define `aws_iam_user` resource somewhere but am not sure when and which roles to include.

Lambda function is in a separate `lambda.tf` file, as:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "handler_lambda" {
  description = "The lambda handles webhook events from captainai."

  filename      = "data/captainai_webhook_handler.zip"
  function_name = "captainai_webhook_handler"
  role             = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn
  handler          = "captainai_webhook_handler.lambda_handler"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("data/captainai_webhook_handler.zip")
  runtime          = "python3.8"
  timeout          = 120
  memory_size      = 512

  tags = var.service_tags

  environment {
    variables = {
      WEBSOCKET_HTTP_HOST          = var.websocket_http_host
      WEBSOCKET_HTTP_HOST_LOGIN    = var.websocket_http_host_login
      WEBSOCKET_HTTP_HOST_PASSWORD = var.websocket_http_host_password
      CAPTAINAI_SECRET_TOKEN       = var.captainai_secret_token
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "api_gateway" {
  statement_id  = "AllowAPIGatewayInvoke"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.handler_lambda.arn
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

  source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.handler_gateway.execution_arn}/*/*"
}
```

Comment: And where is the Lambda function `handler_lambda` defined?

Comment: Can you add an additional forward slash and wildcard to the `source_arn` in the `aws_lambda_permission`, i.e., `source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.handler_gateway.execution_arn}/*/*/*"` and try with that?

Comment: Did not help. I guess my Terraform IAM user is not set properly ( missing: `"iam:PassRole"` I think) but I am not sure how to set it.

Comment: Well, you'd need to add that policy rule to your policy or ask someone to add it.